# Pass a variable from batch to a file and execute it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to simply pass a variable from batch to a file, then execute that file with the variable. How can I achieve this?

**Batch:**

```
@echo off
set /p var=Name:
::Then pass %var% to a file and execute it.
for /f "delims=" %%L in (name.txt) do %%L
```

**File:**

```
echo Your name must be %var%.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%L in (name.txt) do call %%L
```

Would have been an idea to show expected results.